# How do I pass multiple arguments to a Pandas UDF in PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm working with the following snippet:

```
from cape_privacy.pandas.transformations import Tokenizer

max_token_len = 5


@pandas_udf("string")

def Tokenize(column: pd.Series)-> pd.Series:
  tokenizer = Tokenizer(max_token_len)
  return tokenizer(column)


spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("name", Tokenize("name"))
```

Since Pandas UDF only uses Pandas series I'm unable to pass the `max_token_len` argument in the function call `Tokenize("name")`.

Therefore I have to define the `max_token_len` argument outside the scope of the function.

The workarounds provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845951/pyspark-multiple-parameters-for-pandas-udf-grouped-agg) weren't really helpful.
Are there any other possible workarounds or alternatives to this issue?

Please Advise

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After trying a myriad of approaches, I found an effortless solution as illustrated below:

I created a *wrapper* function (`Tokenize_wrapper`) to wrap the *Pandas UDF* (`Tokenize_udf`) with the wrapper function returning the *Pandas UDF's* function call.

```
def Tokenize_wrapper(column, max_token_len=10):

  @pandas_udf("string")
  def Tokenize_udf(column: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(max_token_len)
    return tokenizer(column)

  return Tokenize_udf(column)



df = df.withColumn("Name", Tokenize_wrapper("Name", max_token_len=5))
```

Using partial functions (@Vaebhav's answer) did actually make this issue's implementation difficult.

Comment: How do you return the tokenizer from the UDF function? is there any way?

Comment: @AbdulWahab can you elaborate?

Comment: but do you get any performance boost if you use the wrapper function?

Comment: @Moj Not in this case, as pandas is pretty inefficient for big data

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does) and directly specifying an additional **argument(s)** in your UDF signature

## Data Preparation

```
input_list = [
               (1,None,111)    
               ,(1,None,120)
              ,(1,None,121)
              ,(1,None,124)
              ,(1,'p1',125)
              ,(1,None,126)
              ,(1,None,146)
              ,(1,None,147)
             ]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,['id','p_id','timestamp'])

sparkDF.show()

+---+----+---------+
| id|p_id|timestamp|
+---+----+---------+
|  1|null|      111|
|  1|null|      120|
|  1|null|      121|
|  1|null|      124|
|  1|  p1|      125|
|  1|null|      126|
|  1|null|      146|
|  1|null|      147|
+---+----+---------+
```

## Partial

```
def add_constant(inp,cnst=5):
    return inp + cnst


cnst_add = 10

partial_func = partial(add_constant,cnst=cnst_add)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('Constant',partial_func(F.col('timestamp')))
                 
sparkDF.show()

+---+----+---------+----------------+
| id|p_id|timestamp|Constant_Partial|
+---+----+---------+----------------+
|  1|null|      111|             121|
|  1|null|      120|             130|
|  1|null|      121|             131|
|  1|null|      124|             134|
|  1|  p1|      125|             135|
|  1|null|      126|             136|
|  1|null|      146|             156|
|  1|null|      147|             157|
+---+----+---------+----------------+
```

## UDF Signature

```
cnst_add = 10

add_constant_udf = F.udf(lambda x : add_constant(x,cnst_add),IntegerType())


sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('Constant_UDF',add_constant_udf(F.col('timestamp')))

sparkDF.show()

+---+----+---------+------------+
| id|p_id|timestamp|Constant_UDF|
+---+----+---------+------------+
|  1|null|      111|         121|
|  1|null|      120|         130|
|  1|null|      121|         131|
|  1|null|      124|         134|
|  1|  p1|      125|         135|
|  1|null|      126|         136|
|  1|null|      146|         156|
|  1|null|      147|         157|
+---+----+---------+------------+
```

Similarly You can transform your function as below -

```
from functools import partial

max_token_len = 5

def Tokenize(column: pd.Series,max_token_len=10)-> pd.Series:
  tokenizer = Tokenizer(max_token_len)
  return tokenizer(column)

Tokenize_udf = F.udf(lambda x : Tokenize(x,max_token_len),StringType())

Tokenize_partial = partial(Tokenize,max_token_len=max_token_len)

spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("name", Tokenize_udf("name"))
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("name", Tokenize_partial("name"))
```

Comment: I see that the answer you have provided is with respect to `UDF`. Will the answer apply to `Pandas UDF` as well?

Comment: What is `F` in `F.udf`?

Comment: `NameError: name 'add_constant' is not defined`

Comment: Updated the answer , added the missing function def

Comment: import pyspark.sql.functions as F

Comment: Quite confused with your solution here, Are you replacing UDF Functions with Partial Functions?

Comment: Partial Functions is a wrapper concept , rather an a UDF , you define a UDF and wrap it around a partial function

Comment: Sounds Great! Would you mind adding some explanation to your answer before I accept it?

Comment: Just to confirm, You've added the `Tokenize_udf ` for comparison with `Tokenize_partial` yeah?